How to set/force a timezone?
MacOS (14.6.1) believes it's in Japan and stubbornly refuses to change that.
Here's a screenshot:

Problem is, that the Time zone setting is disabled, hence it can't be changed. Question now is, how to force a different timezone?
Any advise is welcome. Thank you.

Can you not change the 'Closest city' at the bottom of the pane?

@IconDaemon Yes, changing the closest city still works, but only Japanese cities are listed.

You should add that detail to your question!

The Github page shows various timezone commands available in Terminal: https://gist.github.com/ddre54/1e217fbd7e28b5e864dfac31759e66e7

@IconDaemon Thank you very much for sharing this link. sudo systemsetup -settimezone Europe/Paris fixed the time zone. GUI is still broken though, but that's not a big thing.

You should run the systemsetup command to list the available timezones:
sudo systemsetup -listtimezones
The execute this command to set the timezone you need:
sudo systemsetup -settimezone [your timezone]
Examples:
sudo systemsetup -settimezone Europe/Rome
or
sudo systemsetup -settimezone America/Costa_Rica
